# Is this a question on $Q_L$ vector reflection?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

What is the reflection of v = [2 1 –3$]^T$ in the line with equation [x y z$]^T$ = t[2 0 -2$]^T$?

I've tried the $Q_L$ vector formula, and I got:

[3 -1 -2$]^T$

Is this correct? Is it $Q_L$ or something else?

Comment: You can check your own work. The line must bisect the angle between the vector and its reflection. Since the vector and its reflection are the same length, their angle bisector is very easy to compute.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. Can you just tell me if it's $Q_L$ or not? It's not a part of the sections covered in class, and I'm having a hard time figuring it out.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by “$Q_L$.” Show the steps that you took to get the answer and someone will be able to tell you if they were appropriate.